# BIND based DNS server for local server

Tags: dns, bind, local

I'm currently trying to set up a dns server for home server system, such that I can visit external websites as normal, but when I visit 'http://example.local' on any device in the network it redirects to my home server IP. I know I can use a hosts file to achieve this, but there are limitations to that method which mean it's not an ideal solution.

So far I have managed to set up BIND on a Raspberry Pi I am using as a dns server. However, I have been struggling for a few days now to work out how to set up zones correctly to mean that 'http://example.local' will point to my development server.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. If you need any more information let me know, I didn't want to just dump a load of contents of files if the content is irrelevant.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I have been struggling for a few days now to work out how to set up zones correctly to mean that `http://example.local` will point to my development server.

In e.g `/etc/bind/named.conf.local`, you will like want an entry similar to the following:

```
# Local domains

zone "example.local" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.example.local";
    allow-transfer { none; };
};
```

A minimal zone file example:

*ex. /etc/bind/db.example.local*

```
; Enables use of e.g. http://example.local/

$TTL 3600
@     IN SOA     ns.example.local admin.example.local. (
    2020042101 ; serial
    8H ; Refresh period
    4H ; Retry interval
    4W ; Expire time
    1D ; Negative caching TTL
)

# Required name server records (DNS server IP)
@     NS     ns.example.local.
ns    IN A   192.168.0.10

# A record for example.local (Development server IP)
example.local.    IN A    192.168.0.20

# A records for sub-domains of example.local
# e.g. "raspberry.example.local"
raspberry         IN A    192.168.0.10  
router            IN A    192.168.1.1
localhost         IN A    127.0.0.1
```

**Zone Notes**

- `@` is a replacement for e.g. `example.local.`, which you would normally specify in the positions occupied by `@`. <sup>1</sup> You can simply use `example.local.` if you desire (i.e. if it makes it clearer).
- `admin.example.local` is actually an email address, with `.` substituting for the normal `@` symbol. This does not need to be a real/working email address.
- The serial value for a zone file needs to be updated whenever you make changes.
- The actual format of the serial value numbering doesn't matter (as long as the number increases) but the common way of numbering zone files is YEAR-MONTH-DAY-VERSION. So e.g. `2020042101` would represent the first version of the given file zone file on April 21, 2020.
- For the `ns`  A record, the IP should be the IP of the Raspberry Pi (or whatever is running your DNS server)
- For the `example.local.` A record, the IP should be the local IP of your development server.
- Sub-domain records can point to any IP you want.

**General Notes**

- Your router will need to know the IP address of your DNS server on your local network in order to use it (i.e. so other devices can find `example.local`).
- Since your router will need to be configured to use your local DNS server (rather than e.g. your ISPs), you will need to ensure that your DNS server is configured to either resolve unknown domains itself or forward those requests upstream (e.g. to your ISP). Otherwise, you won't be able to access anything outside your local network (ex. the internet).
- Make certain to use a trailing `/` when specifying local addresses in the browser URL bar (ex. use `example.local/` rather than just `example.local`). Otherwise, Chrome-based browsers (e.g. Chrome, Firefox, Opera) may not resolve the domain correctly.
- For current versions of Firefox, you may need to [disable DNS over HTTPs (DoH)](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-dns-over-https).

---

<sup>1</sup> *Technically, `@` is a [substitution based on the `$ORIGIN` directive in a zone file](https://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/origin.html) (e.g. `$ORIGIN example.local.`) but, while explicitly defining `$ORIGIN` is recommended, BIND will synthesize this directive and its corresponding value from the zone name (e.g. `zone "example.local"`) if it isn't present.*

---

*Further reading: [DNS for Rocket Scientists](https://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/)*